# Add application icon to air app while packaging with adt.jar: how to?

Tags: apache-flex, build, air, packaging

I built air app with icon in the past with flash builder, and everything was fine.

Now I have to build another app with adt(air developer tool), but I experience weird problems.

1. If I just place icon path relative to 'src' folder to app descriptor (as usual), it says:
   `error 303: Icon icon.png is missing from package`.
2. If I use `icon.png` without path in app descriptor and then put this file everywhere(to root dir, to assets, to src, to build destination and so on), it again says `error 303: Icon icon.png is missing from package`.
3. If I try to add icon path to adt args like `<arg value="icon.png"/>` ( and put it to output folder as it seems that all path are relative to it in my case), it says `The path icon.png is restricted. If you were trying to package Icon.png you should correct the case`.
4. When I point to original file location ( `<arg value="../src/assets/icon.png"/>`), it outputs `File ..\src\assets\icon.png is not relative to directory E:\projQ\flex\MyProject\bin` (this `bin` directory is actually output directory). I've read unapproved comment on adobe forum that this is due to some sandbox limitations, but I'm not even sure that sandbox exists for adt( if it exists, then why? )

**So, what shall I do to successfully add icon to that app?** 
I guess that using tools like resHacker to project's `.exe` will not help as `.exe` is just a launcher for `.swf` file, and anyway I consider that this awful way leads to the dark side of programming.

(P.S. can't add 'adt' tag that relates to adobe, not android.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice. At last I've found the solution. So, the requirements for including icon while packaging manually with adt are:

1. Add file name to application descriptor without using any `..` .
2. I beg you, don't even try to name your icon file `icon.png`. It is obvious name, and it was obvious for creators of `adt`. So it seems that they are renaming some files to `icon.png` or generating output to such file. Or put this file into some subdirectory of directory that is used as root by `adt`. Actually, error output exactly tells you to avoid using path icon.png. `Correct the case` phrase (which confused me) means `rename your icon or move it deeper in directory hierarchy`
3. Add path to your icon as command line argument to `adt`.

After generation you will see your icon inside generated output folder. You can remove it and application will still appear with your icon as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an elaboration on the first point in the answer above to clarify for people like me who have been struggling with this issue.

The error reads "is not relative to directory", but what it means is "is not a child of directory". Basically even if you're trying to use a valid relative path, it expects it to point to something *under* your working directory. In my case the following trick worked:

`./../..build/executable.swf`

Replaced with

`-C ./../.. build/executable.swf`

-C makes ADT change directory to the one two levels above, and then you can specify the necessary file.

After playing with ADT a bit more, I now realise why it does that - the path you give to it will become the path within the package. So in the example above the file will be available inside the package at `build/executable.swf`. If you wish to make it available at package's root level, change the -C directive to the following:

`-C ./../../build executable.swf`